# Plot a bubble chart in d3.js by giving an local geojson file as an input

Tags: javascript, geojson, d3, chart

This is the content in my geojson file

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "profit": 326,
        "npa": 174.000000
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "profit": 1762,
        "npa": 1683.000000
    }
}]
}
```

I am storing the data in a taluks.geojson. I want to give this local geojson file as an input and display the bubble chart based on the value profit.

My bubble chart is based on this : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269